# Sending email with generated PDF (best practice, non-coding)

Tags: email-attachments

I have all the mechanisms set up. I am creating offer, then I can generate PDF.

I am wondering, what would be the beset practice?

Should I generate PDF each time on form save for later use? 
Should I generate the PDF just before sending email?

Answer (score 0):

That's simple.
If the expected behaviour is to return response for submitting the form without waiting for an email to be sent, then generate pdf just before sending it. This way your HTTP response will be much faster.

Comment: Doing it this way, will I get delay for flash message - 'Email was sent successfully'? PDF needs to be generated.

Comment: Flash message? There was nothing like this in the question. The overall time of the entire flow: submit form, generate pdf, send email will always be almost the same (any difference won't be noticeable). The only question is if you want to send the HTTP response as soon as possible or wait for the entire flow to be completed. If you want to poll then for status of the background task to show a message that an email has been sent, then it's a different thing but completely unaffected by the way you trigger pdf generation.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Well, here is my flow: I will be creating offer by some form. At the end I will be sending an email with generated PDF and telling user that email was send successfully. Sometimes I will send email later on, when offer was created in past. This is what worries me, will the generation affect some delay? Or is this going to be fast? I don't want to user wait too long.